# Pass variable from controller to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to pass the key variable set in my controller method to my model in method key.

## uploadscontroller.rb

```
def create
  @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
  @upload.upload_file = params[:file]
  @upload.emission_id = params[:id]
  key = Emission.find(params[:id]).key
end
```

## upload.rb

**UPDATE**

I need to use the key from controller self.path route

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'action_view'
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
  belongs_to :emission
  attr_accessor :upload_file
  before_save :upload_file
    def key=(val)
    @variable = val
end

def upload_file=(imcoming_file)

    #en caso de que vengan mas de uno
    imcoming_file.each do |key, value|
        self.name = value.original_filename
        self.tipe = value.content_type
        @data = value.read
        self.path = 'uploads/' + @variable + self.name
        self.md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(@data)
        numer = @data.size
        self.size= number_to_human_size(numer)
        self.time_to_air = "10"

        #Mueve el archivo al directorio
        File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', self.name), 'wb') do |file|
            file.write(@data)


        end
    end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

From controller:

```
@upload.key = key
```

Comment: Key is not in the database is only one variable I want to spend a model to work with

Comment: So you need to send model other variables too? What's your model btw?

Comment: i upadte the post, please check.

Comment: @cii I'm still confused. You have `key` variable defined in controller (last line of `create` method`) and want to pass it to `@upload` variable. Right?

Comment: Then why can't you use @upload.key = key? You have key= defined in your Upload class